# How to get data from sql database using dapper in parallel/multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am trying to get data from sql server using dapper. I have requirement to export 460K records stored in a Azure sql database. I decided to get data in batches, so I getting record of 10k records in each batch. I have planned to get the records in Parallel, so I added async methods to a list of task and did `Task.WhenAll`. The code works fine when i run locally but after deployed to k8s cluster, I am getting data read issue for some records. I am new to multi threading and I don't how to handle this issue. I tried to do a lock inside the method but the system crashes,  Below is my code, the code might be clumsy because I was trying many solution to fix the issue.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
{
  tableviewWithCondition.startRow = startRow;
  resultData.Add(_tableviewRepository.GetTableviewRowsByPagination(tableviewExportCondition.TableviewName, modelMappingGroups, tableviewWithCondition.startRow, builder, pageSize, appName, i));
  startRow += tableviewWithCondition.pageSize;
}

foreach(var task in resultData)
{ 
   if (task != null)
   {
      dataToExport.AddRange(task.Result);
   }
}
```

This is the method I implemented to get data from azure sql database using dapper.

```
public async Task<(IEnumerable<int> unprocessedData, IEnumerable<dynamic> rowData)> GetTableviewRowsByPagination(string tableName, IEnumerable<MappingGroup> tableviewAttributeDetails,
           int startRow, SqlBuilder builder, int pageSize = 100, AppNameEnum appName = AppNameEnum.OptiSoil, int taskNumber = 1)
        {
            var _unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkServices.Build(appName.ToString());
            List<int> unprocessedData = new List<int>();
            try
            {
                var columns = tableviewAttributeDetails.Select(c => { return $"{c.mapping_group_value} [{c.attribute}]"; });
                var joinedColumn = string.Join(",", columns);
                builder.Select(joinedColumn);
                var selector = builder.AddTemplate($"SELECT /**select**/ FROM {tableName} with (nolock) /**innerjoin**/ /**where**/ /**orderby**/ OFFSET {startRow} ROWS FETCH NEXT {(pageSize == 0 ? 100 : pageSize)} ROWS ONLY");

                using (var connection = _unitOfWork.Connection)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var data = await connection.QueryAsync(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters);
                    Console.WriteLine($"data completed for task{taskNumber}");
                    return (unprocessedData, data);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    Console.WriteLine($"InnerException: {ex.InnerException.Message}");

                Console.WriteLine($"Error in fetching from row {startRow}");
                unprocessedData.Add(startRow);
                return (unprocessedData, null);
            }
            finally
            {
                _unitOfWork.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

The above code works fine locally, but in server I am getting below issue.

> Exception: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught).

> InnerException:  The WriteAsync method cannot be called when another write operation is pending.

How to avoid this issue when fetch data in parallel tasks?

Comment: Where are those exceptions being caught and what are their stack traces?

Comment: Actually I fixed the issue by increasing the sqlconnection timeout. I found the this issues occurs when the connection is trying to open. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same connection and trying to execute multiple commands over it (I'm assuming this because of the naming), also should you be disposing the unit of work?

Rather than :

```
 using (var connection = _unitOfWork.Connection)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var data = await connection.QueryAsync(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters);
                    Console.WriteLine($"data completed for task{taskNumber}");
                    return (unprocessedData, data);
                }
```

Create a new connection for each item, if this is what you truly want to do. I imagine, and this is an educated guess it's working locally because of timing.

Also look into Task.WhenAll it's a better way collect all the results up. Rather than :

```
foreach(var task in resultData)
{ 
   if (task != null)
   {
      dataToExport.AddRange(task.Result);
   }
}
```

calling result on a task is usually bad practice.